# What is the exact difference between Fix and Self on the Calculus of Constructions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, agda, idris

The [Self Types for Dependently Typed Lambda Encodings](https://fermat.github.io/document/papers/rta-tlca.pdf) paper (by Peng Fu and Aaron Stump) proposes self types, which are, supposedly, sufficient to encode the induction principle and [Scott-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mogensen%E2%80%93Scott_encoding) datatypes on the [Calculus of Constructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_constructions), without making the system inconsistent or introducing paradoxes.

The notation of that paper is too heavy for me to fully understand how to implement it.

What is, precisely, the main difference of Fix and Self? Or, in other words: in what points a naively implemented Fix should be restricted, so that it leaves no inconsistencies on the core calculus?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think CS or TCS might be more appropriate sites for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I have understood after browsing the paper.

A `Fix` type satisfies the typing equivalence (assuming equirecursive types)

```
G |- M : Fix x. t   <=>     G |- M : t{Fix x. t / x}
```

i.e. you can unfold the type over itself. Note how the term `M` does not play any role here. If using isorecursive types, `M` would get some isomorphism applied (e.g. a Haskell's `newtype` constructor), but it is not that important.

Instead, Self types satisfy the following

```
G |- M : Self x. t   <=>     G |- M : t{M / x}
```

Now, `x` is not a type variable, but a term variable. The term gets "moved" inside the type. This is not a recursive type at all.

Comment: Hmm so basically a term with type `Self x . type` has a copy of the term itself? Does that actually allow for Scott encodings? The paper seems to propose the solution to `O(n)` matching is Parigot encoding, not Scott... hmm...

Comment: @MaiaVictor Roughly, yes. I don't know about how complex encodings are there -- I'd need to read the paper more carefully.